# RxJava: Create an Observable during HTTP Request that keeps running after request returns

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, observable, rx-java

I have an HTTP request that triggers a long-running task (multiple HTTP requests to another service) that is supposed to be completed in the background while the original requests complete.

So what I do is

```
public void triggerWork(@RequestBody SomeObject somObject) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(startWorkAndReturn(somObject), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

public void startWorkAndReturn(SomeObject someObject) {
    Observable.create(observableEmitter -> {
      // do the work with someObject here and at some time call
      observableEmitter.onNext("result");
    }).subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Object o) {
        // called at some unknown time
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
        // currently not used as all the work is done in onNext but maybe that's a mistake
      }
    });
    return;
  }
```

But this seems to block the request until all the work has been done. Which already seems odd to me, since I never call onComplete, which in itself might be a mistake. But still, I am wondering how to create a request that immediately returns after triggering a background worker.

Is Flowables the solution here? I am going to refactor to those anyways to handle backpressure. Or do I need to create a background worker Thread? What is the best practice here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Observable.fromCallable{} since you need emit only single event. That will handle onCompleate call. From information you share I don`t know how can you properly handle disposable. You should add subscribeOn() and observeOn() operators that will define on which thread 'work' should be processed and result should be observed.

Docs ref:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html